Contradiction on the existence of a regular graph of diameter 2
I am studying certain finite algebraic structures $X$ that allow me to create a simple undirected $d-$regular connected graph $\Gamma(X)$ with $|X|$ vertices, and where the value of $d$ can be determined from the structure of $X$.
Based on computational experiments, it seems that the diameter of $\Gamma(X)$ is never greater than 3. I aim to prove this observation using graph-theoretic arguments, an area with which I unfortunately lack expertise. Here is my current approach:
Assume, for contradiction, that there exists an $X$ such that $diam(\Gamma(X))>3$. Then, the complement $\overline{\Gamma(X)}$ is a $(|X|-d-1)$-regular (connected) graph with $|X|$ vertices and it necessarily has a diameter of 2 (source: Diameter of a Connected Graph). I aim to demonstrate the non-existence of such a complement graph.
Question 1: Are there any graph-theoretic properties of $\Gamma(X)$ that I can utilize to prove the impossibility of its complement? For example, if I could establish that $\Gamma(X)$ is, say, distance regular, then... (unfortunately, distance regularity does not apply).
Question 2: Are there any other effective graph-theoretic general approaches that I am overlooking?
Other strategies I am exploring/considering:

A graph with a diameter of 2 and a (maximum) degree of $d$ can have at most $d^2+1$ vertices (though this bound seems insufficient for my goals).
The adjacency matrix of a $d$-regular graph has $d$ as its largest eigenvalue.

Thanks in advance.
